# Updating UITableView in Xamarin iOS when the dataSource for the table changes dynamically

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, reloaddata

I have a UITableView and I have set the datasource for the table using a 'List'.I know the size of the list initially and have set the number of cells of the table as same as the list length.I am fetching the data for the table in background meaning the list data changes dynamically even when the table is being displayed. When there is fast swipe from the user,the tableview displays empty cells for some data which is still being fetched.

Issue:
When I reach the end of the tableview and when the tableview is still displaying empty cells,and I try to scroll up the cell is redrawn from bottom showing the data meaning effectively the data is 'refreshed' from the bottom of the tableview.

What I tried:
I tried reloading the tableview,reloading the cells as soon as I get the data from backend,but still this issue persists.I tried reloading the tableview using InvokeOnMainThread,but still this problem persists.

What I think is happening:
The data fetching is completed in background when the tableview is displaying empty cells and when I do scroll up again the cells are 'repainted' to display the data.I am using reusable cells in my tableview.

Is there any way to reload the cells as soon I get the data and update the cells.That is,when the tableview is displaying empty cells and as soon as data fetching is complete,reload the data in the tableview.

Answer (score 2):

try calling

```
yourTableView.ReloadData()
```

when your data is finished loading.

Also, make sure to prepare your table view cells for display using

```
public override void PrepareForReuse() {//your code here }
```

in the UITableViewCell class.

Comment: I tried ReloadTableData in InvokeOnMainThread but still displays blank cells.If I scroll to some point and simply wait,even when the data is fetched the tableview fails to show the data and displays blank cells.Only when I scroll up the data is displayed.Any other direction in which I can try?

Comment: I am calling ReloadTableData on main UI thread but still I am seeing blank cells itself.Am I missing something here?

Comment: are you sure youre using "ReloadData" and not "ReloadTableData"?

Comment: Sorry,ReloadTableData is the method I use to call mytable.ReloadData.Forgot to mention that.